# MSBuild configuration error WDK 8.1 Visual Studio 2015 to build kernel mode driver

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, driver

I'm struggling with VS 2015 C++ 'Platform Toolset' configuration property to build a test *.sys kernel driver I want play around this night.

So, this is a fresh new installation of VS 2015 Pro (update 1) plus WDK 8.1 (just downloaded) running on clean Win 8.1

All libs and headers like ntddk.h are in place.

But `C++ Solution Explorer -> General -> Platform Toolset` does not eat every option:

```
Visual Studio 2015 (v140)  -- ok
Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)  -- ok
WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.1  -- error
WindowsKernelModeDriver8.1  -- error (need this one)
WindowsUserModeDriver8.1  -- error
```

Nags as follows:

> One or more values are invalid. MSBuild returned the following error:
>   The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\v120\Microsoft.cpp.props" was not
>   found. (Directory exists though!) Confirm that the path in the
>    declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.12.props

I don't know what it could be. Am I supposed to have WDK 10 towards to VS2015?!

Anyway, I need the ability to build the driver on VS 2015.
Could it be directed compiler scripts?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok

Moving to WDK 10 helped!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-drivers/develop/building_a_driver

> Ensure that you have the same version of SDK and WDK installed on your
>   computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver update for visual studio if you are working on visual studio then you have to get the proper update for it. I've a link please follow this link and you will get rid off from this problem..[enter link description here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit)

[enter link description here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit)